# mysql query for posts with multiple comments

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that returns all posts thats the user is associated with (this is working great)

eg

```
//friends
wallusers.mem_id IN (".$matches.") 
// themselves    
OR wallusers.mem_id =".$user_id." 
//tagged in
OR wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%'


    $qry = "SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.type,wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.title AS thetitle,wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,wallposts.date_created
    FROM wallposts,wallusers
    where (wallusers.mem_id IN (".$matches.") OR wallusers.mem_id =".$user_id." OR wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%') and wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.userid
    order by wallposts.p_id desc 
    limit ".$show_more_post.", 10";
```

I now want to add the comments into this query, so that if someone tags the user in a comment it is returned in this query.

this would be joined on:

```
wallposts.p_id = wallcomments.post_id
```

the where clause would be:

```
wallcomments.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%'
```

There are multiple comments for each post and I am struggling to work out how I would implement this, would i use INNER JOIN?

**EDIT:  I only need the post in the query the comments don't need to be there. So if tagged in comment of post include post in query.**

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this could do the job , yes you can use inner join

```
 SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.type,wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.title AS thetitle,wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,wallposts.date_created
 FROM wallposts,wallusers
 INNER JOIN wallcomments 
 ON  wallposts.p_id = wallcomments.post_id
 WHERE (wallusers.mem_id IN (".$matches.") OR wallusers.mem_id =".$user_id." OR wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%') and wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.userid AND wallcomments.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%'
ORDER BY wallposts.p_id desc 
 LIMIT ".$show_more_post.", 10
```

EDIT:

```
  SELECT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.type,wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.title AS thetitle,wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,wallposts.date_created
 FROM wallposts
 INNER JOIN wallusers
 ON  wallposts.userid = wallusers.mem_id     // LOOK IF wallusers.mem_id is same as wallposts.userid , im not sure about your table
 INNER JOIN wallcomments 
 ON  wallposts.p_id = wallcomments.post_id
 WHERE (wallusers.mem_id IN (".$matches.") OR wallusers.mem_id =".$user_id." OR wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%') and wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.userid AND wallcomments.tagedpersons LIKE '%".$user_id."%'
ORDER BY wallposts.p_id,wallposts.type,wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.title
 LIMIT ".$show_more_post.", 10
```

Comment: this is not working as expected. Dont think my question was structured correctly. I only want to get the post of that comment so dont actually need the comment data in the query. The query just need to have the associated post included in the query

Comment: getting this error #1054 - Unknown column 'wallposts.p_id' in 'on clause'